# Browser events in JSF

Tags: javascript, events, jsf, browser

Is there anyway we can catch browser events like "Back", "Forward" in JSF backing bean  or Javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

For javascript check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136937/is-there-a-way-to-catch-the-back-button-event-in-javascript).

And as u catch in javascript you can mark on backing bean using `<a4j:jsFunction>`