# Catch back-button (keep one history entry, no visible hash-tags)

Tags: javascript, ajax

We are currently building an advanced JS/AJAX-based service, and allowing the back-button to function in a meaningful way is obviously important. I've looked around some, and been in-contact with iframe-hash/anchor-solutions before, but the ones I've seen and found are all based on the idea of going back/forwards in a page structure. What I'm looking for is to find a way to bind the back-button to act as an alternative for "close" / "cancel".

The solution to what I'm looking for is simple, to almost **always** keep exactly one additional back-history entry (except for when "we" decide the user is at the "start"), **without** showing a hash-tag in the location bar.

I did have a try at implementing it myself, a hidden iframe for which I change the hash, worked well, in all browsers but IE, it refused to update the hash-tag for me when pressing back. Are there any solutions out there that solve this problem (trap back-button, no visible hash-tag)? Or any simple cross-browser solutions for dealing with hidden iframe hashtags?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136937/is-there-a-way-to-catch-the-back-button-event-in-javascript

Comment: Why not just leave "my" backbutton where "I" decide it should "be" and take "your" idea of "start" and shove "it?" With hash-tags "on", if you please.

Comment: @Pete Wilson I understand your general hate towards people messing with the back-button. This however, is as stated in my question, for an "advanced service". Users will intentionally visit and login, and having the back-button work intuitively is of high importance... just as for all other pages you visit. The difference being that we don't want to show hashtags because they cannot have any actual meaning in our context (we work with depth, not pages) and we must keep one back-history because the depth is "unknown".

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish what you want to do without breaking the back button. You just haven't thought the problem through. That is, you picked the most obvious solution without applying your creativity to come up with another that's just as good and very likely would be considerably better: more intuitive, more powerful, and so on. Only speaking from my experience, but I believe a better solution is waiting in your soul to be uncovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the partial answer, but this looks promising: http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/

I'd like to keep informed of your progress on this, it's a useful thing if it's practical to implement.

Dan

Comment: I looked around some more, but didn't really find anything that really matched my needs. So I decided to go back to writing my own minimal implementation instead. I found that my initial issue was that setting hashes for an iframe doesn't really seem to create the same behavior. The solution I ended up with is to use the HTML4-hash technique, but stripped to the bare minimum and only being able to use "#/" as hash... and using the HTML5-history for the browsers that support it (no visible hashtags; FF4, Chrome). Works very well it seems (even if double-clicking the back-button).