# redirecting to a specific page when clicking browser's back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, history, back, fragment-identifier

it's a bit of a nooby question, but there it goes:
i have a site where the user can only navigate from page to page via next and back buttons. i.e there is a wizard the user must follow. part of the wizard includes different pages and part includes the same page but with changing divs (but from user experience its a different page).
i would like to simply redirect the user to the first page of the wizard, whenever he clicks on the browser's back button.
if possible and simple, i prefer doing so without the use of (yet another) plugin.

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to catch the back button event in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136937/is-there-a-way-to-catch-the-back-button-event-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to prevent the default behavior of the browser's back button - no browser allows that because it would pose potential security risks and a bad user experience.

With that said, there are tricks out there that may satisfy your needs.
Check this out: 
[Detecting Back Button/Hash Change in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172957/detecting-back-button-hash-change-in-url)

Comment: hi kon, i'm not trying to prevent the browser's back button. all i'm trying to do is and another "history mark" that will point to the fist page...

Comment: and since my goal is fairly simple i'm trying to refrain from using plugins which is what they suggest in the link you have provided. thanks :)

Comment: You don't need to use any plugins.  I didn't send you there for any specific answer, but just in general.  Here's what you want:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136937/is-there-a-way-to-catch-the-back-button-event-in-javascript  In fact, this question is a duplicate.

Comment: it's not a duplicate question and the link you have provided does not include an answer to my question. i'm not looking for a way to poll the location.hash. my question was simpler, how do I add a reference to the first page...

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways but since you don't want to use plugins (I guess libraries too) you can just use the browser's function for that:

```
window.location
```

Use this for reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Or if you want to use a library, I recommend going for page.js since it's really easy to use:

for example:

```
page.redirect('/home')
```