# How to get the before hash change event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, back-button, hashchange

I need help to find the way to get the event before http URL hash changes.

My requirement :

http://example.com/a#b to http://example.com/a#c

Whenever user changes the hash value in the browser header, I want to check whether user has entered all the required fields in the current page. If user does not enter all the required details on the current page and if he tries to navigate back to previous page by clicking on back button or refresher the page, I want to show confirmation message to user whether he wants to save the existing changes or discard them.

If you can help me on finding any solution approach that would be great help.

Thanks for your help in advanced.

Naru

Comment: Check this SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208627/how-to-capture-browsers-back-forward-button-click-event-or-hash-change-event-in

Comment: Look at jQuery form validation plugin: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ and then look at http://api.jquery.com/unload/