# Detect Browser back button press - Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Is It possible to detect a click on a browser's back button using Jquery/Jquery mobile?

I have a small quiz application - I need to reset variables if the user clicks the phones back button mid way through playing the game.

Thanks for your time!

Cheers
Paul

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136937/is-there-a-way-to-catch-the-back-button-event-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Nope. The page doesn't have access to the browser. This would be a massive security risk. You can add an onunload event to the page, but I really don't recommend this action (please).