# Detect use of Android back button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android

My site has breadcrumbs which highlight which stage in a process the user has reached. The breadcrumbs rely on the browser history to tell which stage should be highlighted when the browser back button is used, but on Android devices using the hardware back button this seems to be bypassed and the highlighted breadcrumb does not change.

My site is not using PhoneGap or anything similar as it's not usually a mobile site, so is it possible to capture use of the Android back button so that I can add an event to set the breadcrumb highlight based on the history log when the button is used, just using JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I just want to know if it is possible to capture the device back button, and if so, how to do it. I don't know of anything to try, as I don't know if it is even accessible to javascript.

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2000319/1739882

Comment: Thanks, but this is not an android app, it is just a website, so I am looking for a way to detect the back button without using Java.

Comment: Ah, I followed the thread of SO answers and eventually got to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136937/is-there-a-way-to-catch-the-back-button-event-in-javascript

Comment: The browser will catch the android back button event and fire popstate. But we wouldn't know if all popstate events come from android back button, or there is also a back button in the broswer.

Answer (score 3):

**1. Use `popstate` event.**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate

```
window.onpopstate = function(e) { 
   updateBreadCrumbObservable();
};
```

**2. Use `onhashchange` event.**

```
window.onhashchange = function(e) {
   updateBreadCrumbObservable();
}
```

You can use event argument to get more description about the event fired.

Comment: Thanks @Navjot Ahuja, I've tested and both events are launched in every navigation through the page but, how can I know if the user has launched it or it has been the android back button? Kind regards

Comment: I've compared ALL event attributes and all of them have the same values :(

Comment: Why do you need to have a separate behaviour for hardware and browser back button? They should technically behave the same way for the user. In that case, answer given by @NavjotAhuja will work fine.

Comment: Sorry perhaps my message was unclear. I meant that how can I know if the user clicks a button (every navigation in page launches both functions) or if the user has pressed return to last page / back button in Android. Thanks and sorry again.

Answer (score 1):

You can put check on inside **onBackPressed** method of the activity and before calling **super.onBackPressed();** trigger the method to call javascript method.

for e.g:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (handleBackPress) {
        myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:backButtonPressed()")
    }else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

in the above example if **handleBackPress** boolean variable is true, then it will try to call **backButtonPressed()** method of javascript file in the webview.

Let me know if you need any explanation or help.

Comment: Nice and +1 but What's `fun` here?

Comment: the code is in kotlin language.. which means it is a function

Comment: in java you can write it like, "public void onBackPressed()" .. :)

Comment: Ohh. I don't have any idea about kotlin. Thanks.

Comment: @RahulKhurana we're not using Java/Android, this is just a mobile site that uses JavaScript