# Single Page application and the back button[AJAX]

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a website that has been entirely designed to operate without generating any browser history other then the main page. This was mostly for security so the browser state and the server never are out of sync.

I want to know if there is a way to intercept the browser "back" button when they are anywhere except on the main page of our site to operate an internal "back" button.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136937/is-there-a-way-to-catch-the-back-button-event-in-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser

Comment: My website does not add any hashes to the URL. Ill try your suggestions though

Answer (score 0):

You can use Push State Navigation to handle browser's back button. Take a look at this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: after working on this for some time, I am re-writing my site to work with get requests to allow back/forward. Thank you for your suggestion.